# using one piece of XML data in multiple place

Tags: xml, xslt, symphony-cms

How do you transform a section of an XML document multiple times?

I'm calling a template from within one stylesheet for a particular node. When I import another utility that transforms that same data, the original stops working.

How do I get both style sheets to work?

Comment: Do you want the result to have two different files, or just have both sets of templates execute for the given XML node(s) and produce different pieces of output in the same result file?

Comment: A sample code would be more bring more elaborated information ..

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to diagnose without seeing the stylesheets, but I suspect that your *importing* stylesheet and *imported* stylesheet have templates with the same match criteria or the same name and the *importing* stylesheet has "overridden" the imported stylesheet template, preventing it from executing.

**Imported stylesheets have a lower precedence than the templates in your top level stylesheet.**

You can use [`<xsl:apply-imports />`](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_apply-imports.asp) within your main stylesheet template to apply the *imported* template for that node.

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <!--First, turn foo into bar -->
  <bar>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </bar>
  <!--Now, apply the template from the imported file to do whatever it does-->
  <xsl:apply-imports />
</xsl:template>
```

You can also use **mode** to define multiple templates for a given node and then apply-templates in different modes to control when they are executed.

http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/modes.html

> For example, if you want to apply
>   style1.xsl or style2.xsl from
>   style.xsl, you could define all
>   templates in style1.xsl with
>   mode="style1" (and use the mode
>   attribute too in all call-template and
>   apply-templates) and all templates in
>   style2.xsl with mode="style2".
>
> Then, you could have a style.xsl
>   styelsheet that contains:

```
<xsl:include href="style1.xsl"/>
<xsl:include href="style2.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="some pattern">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="some test">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="style1"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="style2"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use a template name, not a data match.

Use this

```
<xsl:call-template name="test" />

<xsl:template name="test">
    <!-- content -->
</xsl:template>
```

not this

```
<xsl:template match="test/entry">
    <!-- content -->
</xsl:template>
```